Next 14 middleware does not extracting cookies in Production Deployment
I am using Next.JS middleware to check if user is authenticated or not since getServerSession not working in edge function so i try to authenticate my users manually by check cookies in header it work in development but when deployed on vercel it does not extracting my cookies. I also try withAuth NextAuth middleware but it also not working.
i am using
next: "14.1.3",
next-auth: "^4.22.1",
Link to my Project Repo


import { cookies } from "next/headers";
import { NextResponse, NextRequest } from "next/server";

export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const _cookies = cookies();
  const allCookies = _cookies
    .getAll()
    .map((cookeie) => `${cookeie.name}=${cookeie.value}`)
    .join(";");

  if (!_cookies.get("next-auth.session-token")?.value?.trim()) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/signin", request.url));
  }

  const headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    Cookie: allCookies,
  };

  /**
   * Send a request to /api/auth/session to get the user session
   * process.LOOPBACK_URL can be set as localhost, or your website url
   */
  const url = new URL("/api/auth/session", process.env.LOOPBACK_URL);
  const response = await fetch(url.href, {
    headers: headers,
    cache: "no-store",
  });

  if (response.ok) {
    const session = await response.json();
    if (new Date(session.expires) < new Date()) {
      return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/signin", request.url));
    }
    return NextResponse.next();
  }

  return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/signin", request.url));
}

// See "Matching Paths" below to learn more
export const config = {
  matcher: ["/account", "/analytics"],
};

// Next Auth does not work with Edge Function so we can not use getServerSession of next Auth


import { MongoDBAdapter } from "@auth/mongodb-adapter";
import clientPromise from "@/app/libs/mongodb";
import GoogleAuthProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";

export const authOption: NextAuthOptions = {
  // @ts-ignore
  adapter: MongoDBAdapter(clientPromise),
  providers: [
    GoogleAuthProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID as string,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET as string,
    }),
  ],
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
    maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60, // 30 days
    updateAge: 24 * 60 * 60, // 24 hours
  },
  pages: { signIn: "/signin" },
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET as string,
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user, account, profile }) {
      return token;
    },
  },
};




Have you allowed third-party cookie in your browser?

yes, I even try to change browsers and also disable all extensions.
